# How should the output layer of an LSTM be when the output are word embeddings?

Tags: natural-language-processing, long-short-term-memory, word-embedding, word2vec

I'm having trouble grasping how to output word embeddings from an LSTM model. I'm seeing many examples using a softmax activation function on the output, but for that I would need to output one hot vectors as long as the vocabulary (which is too long). So, should I use a linear activation function on the output to get the word embeddings directly (and then find the closest word) or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, LSTM is not used to get word2vec. Indeed, word2vec is extracted from corpus of words using MLP (Multi Layer Perceptron). There is a great tutorial on how to extract word2wec:
http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/

After representing word as vectors, you feed your text to LSTM in a deep architecture which the last layer must be softmax to categorize your text.

Answer (score 0):

In the research papers, it is not clear how they do that. From what I understood, you need to add a dense layer after your RNN layer. This dense layer is the size of your vocabulary. From my experience, this works even for a large vocabulary (30 000 - 40 000 for me) if you have enough data. Here you don't try to reconstruct the embedding but a one-hot vector of the current word. You can then use a cross-entropy loss. This last layer will have a lot of parameters.

You will see several implementations which are using the MSE loss directly on the word embedding output. Personally I didn't succeed with this approach but if other people could share their experiences, it could be great.